# Every row send e-mail to same recipient

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I receive an Excel file with all planned courses for the coming period and for every row I have to send an e-mail separately to the same recipient.

I would like to create a VBA code that sends an e-mail through OUTLOOK (same recipient) for every row IN EXCEL, with message body all the data from the row A:K, and stop when Column A has no data.

Comment: re: *'but i wasn't able to get it working'* Edit your question to include what you have come up with so far; working or not.

Answer (score 1):

Why re-invent the wheel? Use Word and do a mail merge to email.